# Sorting an ArrayList containing custom objects

Tags: sorting, recursion, arraylist

I want to sort an ArrayList of High scores. The list contains objects, which each contain String name, String category and int score. I want to sort the ArrayList into descending order by score:

This is what I have at the moment, however it crashes the program when the procedure runs:

```
**INITIALIZING ARRAY AND VARIABLES:**
private static ArrayList<HighScore> highScores = new ArrayList<HighScore>();
private static int Last;
private static int First = 0;
private static int PivotValue;
private static  int LeftPointer;
private static int RightPointer;
private static int Pivot;


  **READING IN VALUES INTO ARRAYLIST**
 String File = "src/project/res/highscores.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                HighScore h = new HighScore(line);
                highScores.add(h);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading in high scores!");
        }


**CALLING THE PROCEDURE**
    quickSort(highScores,First,Last);




private static void quickSort(ArrayList<HighScore> highScores2, int first, int last){

        if(first < last)
        {
            PivotValue = highScores2.get(first).getScore();
            LeftPointer = first + 1;
            RightPointer = last;

            while((LeftPointer <= RightPointer))
            {
                while((LeftPointer <= RightPointer)&&(highScores2.get(LeftPointer).getScore() < PivotValue))
                {
                    LeftPointer++; 
                }
                while((highScores2.get(RightPointer).getScore() > PivotValue)&&(LeftPointer <= RightPointer))
                {
                    RightPointer--;
                }
                if(LeftPointer < RightPointer)
                {
                    HighScore temp = highScores2.get(LeftPointer);
                    highScores2.set(RightPointer, highScores2.get(LeftPointer));
                    temp.equals(highScores2.get(RightPointer));
                }
            }

            Pivot = RightPointer;
            HighScore temp = highScores2.get(first);
            highScores2.set(Pivot,highScores2.get(first));
            temp.equals(highScores2.get(Pivot));

            quickSort(highScores2, first, Pivot-1);
            quickSort(highScores2, Pivot + 1, last);
        }


    }
```

Comment: How does it crash the program? Please post the error.

Comment: There are no errors, the GUI just freezes

Comment: Almost guarantee your quicksort implementation isn't terminating then. Tried stepping through it?

Comment: Unless this is homework and you're required to do it in this way, the better way would be to implement the Comparable interface on your HighScore class and override the compareTo function, then use the in-built sort function on your list of HighScore instances.

Comment: OK,How would I do that?